# Type Mismatch , Required: (Recyclerview.Adapter<Recyclerview.ViewHolder>?..Recyclerview.Adapter<*> , found: HomeAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I made this application in Android Studio using Kotlin language. When I made the application an error occurred.

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.pb_home)


        val dataSource = NetworkProvider.providesHttpAdapter().create(HomeDataSource::class.java)
        dataSource.discoverMovie().enqueue(object : Callback<HomeResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<HomeResponse>, response:
                Response<HomeResponse>
            ) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                val results = response.body()?.results
                val itemAdapter = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_home)
                itemAdapter.addItemDecoration(
                    DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity,
                        DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
               itemAdapter.adapter = HomeAdapter (results ?: emptyList())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<HomeResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your `HomeAdapter` class does not look like to be a recyclerview adapter.

Comment: Please show the code of your HomeAdapter class. First line or two only to show what it extends.

Answer (score 1):

**Type Mismatch Error** occurs when you try to assign a value between two different variable types.

```
 val recyclerView                = findViewById(R.id.rv_home) as RecyclerView?
 val adapterOBJ                  = HomeAdapter(results ?: emptyList())
 recyclerView?.layoutManager     = LinearLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
 recyclerView?.adapter           = adapterOBJ
```

Your **HomeAdapter** will be

```
class HomeAdapter (private val alList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

**FYI**

- I assume **`results ?: emptyList()`** holds `ArrayList<String>`.
- Set proper name. **RecyclerView's** Object name **itemAdapter** is not acceptable.

Comment: @Misbagas Solved this yet?

Comment: @Misbagas Okay. You can accept this answer if works. How ? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235